# Parsefloat and currency issues

Tags: javascript, autofill, steam, parsefloat

I am using this variable on autoFill extension to get a string on the page and put it on a field on the same page.

```
minPrice = javascript:(document.getElementsByClassName('market_commodity_orders_header_promote')[1].innerHTML.replace("R$ ",""))
```

[image]

My goal is to add a random number of cents to its final value, but since it's a string even after I remove que "R$", I can't just use math.random. And when I use parseFloat it bugs me even more.

I've tried a lot of different ways, but no success, either I got lots of zeros and wrong decimal cases.

my other tries

```
minPrice  = javascript:((parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('market_commodity_orders_header_promote')[1].innerHTML.replace("R$ ","").replace(",","."))+(Math.random() * (0.120 - 0.0200) + 0.0200)).toFixed(2))

minPrice  = javascript:(parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('market_commodity_orders_header_promote')[1].innerHTML.replace("R$ ","").replace(",",".")).toFixed(2))
```

tried to make it parseInt and divide for 100 to get correct decimal cases, but I keep losing the cents value -- every time I try, the code becomes more and more buggy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you have a string like:

```
R$12.812,12
```

and you want to add a random number of cents to it?  And then convert it back?

If so:

```js
const input = 'R$12.812,12';
const numberOfCents = parseInt(input.replace(/\D/g,''));
const randomNumberOfCents = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
const moneyStr = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR',  {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
}).format((numberOfCents + randomNumberOfCents)/100)
console.log(moneyStr);
```

Comment: My apologies if it's not very clear. 

This line gives me the value and removes the R$, but it's still a string. I get this value egg: 

**R$ 564,91**
after removing the R$, turns into a **564,91**

my goal is to add from 1 to 10 random cents to this value, and for some reason i keep geting too many decimal cases or more than one DOTS or COMMAS.

`code minPrice = javascript:(document.getElementsByClassName('market_commodity_orders_header_promote')[1].innerHTML.replace("R$ ","")) `